# I have multiple lists and I want to filter by the most current

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following bucket AWS schema:

[image]

In my python code, it returns a list of the buckets with their dates.

[image]

I need to stick with the most up-to-date of the two main buckets:

[image]

I am starting in Python, this is my code:

str_of_ints = [7100, 7144]

```
for get_in_scenarioid in str_of_ints:
   resultado = s3.list_objects(Bucket=source,Delimiter='/',Prefix=get_in_scenarioid +'/')
   #print(resultado)

   sub_prefix = [val['Prefix'] for val in resultado['CommonPrefixes']]

   for get_in_sub_prefix in sub_prefix:
    resultado2 = s3.list_objects(Bucket=source,Delimiter='/',Prefix=get_in_sub_prefix) # +'/')      
    #print(resultado2)
  
    get_key_and_last_modified = [val['Key'] for val in resultado2['Contents']] + int([val['LastModified'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for val in resultado2['Contents']])
    
    print(get_key_and_last_modified)
```

Comment: Please provide example of code you have tried.

Comment: I update the publication :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to convert your array into pandas DataFrame and to use group by:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["a",1],["a",2],["a",3],["b",2],["b",4]], columns=["lbl","val"])
df.groupby(['lbl'], sort=False)['val'].max()

lbl
a    3
b    4
```

In your case you would also have to split your label into 2 parts first, better keep in separate column.

**Update:**
Once you split your lable into bucket and sub_bucket, you can return max values like this:

```
dfg = df.groupby("main_bucket")
dfm = dfg.max()
res = dfm.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you. I use groupby main bucket and the maximum of the date. With the data frame I managed to create 3 columns: main_bucket, sub_bucket, date. Example 7144, 7100/202103222050/, 2021-03-23 01:48:07. But the groupby just return 7114, 2021-03-23 01:48:07.

Comment: How can I make the column 'sub_bucket' also return?